# Unity New Input System events not triggering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the new Unity Input System into my game but I'm having such a strange bug I hope someone can help me with. In my player object class I have this:

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        myControls = new MyControls();
        
        myControls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.performed += ctx => LeftClickDown();
        myControls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("_____________playerapi left click performed___");
        myControls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.canceled += ctx => LeftClickUp();
        myControls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.canceled += ctx => Debug.Log("_____________playerapi left click cancelled___");
        
        myControls.Gameplay.SecondaryAction.performed += ctx => RightClickDown();
        myControls.Gameplay.SecondaryAction.canceled += ctx => RightClickUp();
    }
```

And it works fine - I can see in the console the logs appearing when I left click (PrimaryAction.performed). MyControls is the auto-generated C# class that wraps all my actions.

For some reason the exact same code doesn't work in other objects. I made this class just to test it (Monobehaviour with just the Awake hook):

```
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("testmycontrols awake begin___");
        
        ctrls = new MyControls();
        ctrls.Gameplay.Inventory.performed += _ => Debug.Log("testmycontrols inventory pressed___");
        ctrls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("testmycontrols left click performed (awake)___");
        
        ctrls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("testmycontrols left click down___");
        ctrls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.canceled += ctx => Debug.Log("testmycontrols left click released___");
        
        ctrls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("testmycontrols left click performed (start)___");
        ctrls.Gameplay.PrimaryAction.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("testmycontrols left click performed___");

        Debug.Log("testmycontrols awake end___");

    }
```

I can see the awake begin and awake end logs in the console but never the PrimaryAction.performed logs in the console. How can this be? I really don't understand how this is possible. Any tips on what to look for? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You never enabled the actions

Comment: Ah you're right. I didn't see there was another place that I did call .Enable() in my player script. Unbelievable. Thank you. I thought I was going insane.

Comment: +1 both but @BugFinder can you elaborate on the enable action? I have a few working scripts with the new system and I'm not familiar with that notion.

Comment: @Absinthe have a read on the new input documentation then. There are some other ways to use it but this js one of the most common and you need to enable it for it to work

Comment: @BugFinder Sure, I get creating an instance of the auto-generated class (which is nice Unity, thanks:)) but what is enable? Can you point out a page? Thanks.

Comment: @Absinthe https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.8/manual/Actions.html#using-actions

Answer (score -1):

You have to call Enable() on the action to listen for action events - [using actions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.8/manual/Actions.html#using-actions)

I had put an Enable call somewhere in my player script and after a week off, I had completely forgot about it. That's why the player script was working and not anywhere else.